# Changing the cursor highlight color

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I use a theme which has a dark code page backgroung. I love it. The only issue I have is that when I highlight (like to copy/paste for example), I can barely see what is highlighted. The same thing goes for when I do a search (CTRL + F).

Can this be changed in VS 2010?

I'm in `Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Text Editor`, but I can't find the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the `Selected Text` option, but you can change only the background color not the Foreground color